# jquery tab nav URL change

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

I have four tabs in the menu and each have different content, I already have made the tab navigation work with the code below but I want it where I just enter the specific URL following the # and page name in a page, for it to open that page not the first active page.

```
$('.store_tabs li').click(function() {
    /* set active tab */
    setActiveTab($(this).attr('data-tab'), $(this));

});


/* tab activation */
function setActiveTab(dataID, ele) {
    var tab_id = dataID;
    $('.store_tabs li').removeClass('active');
    $('.storelist_tab-content').removeClass('active');
    $(ele).addClass('active');
    $("#" + tab_id).addClass('active');
}
```

Comment: can you edit the post with your html code?

Comment: `jQuery(function() { setActiveTab(window.location.hash) })`?

Comment: sorry it doesnt allow me to edit my question to enter the code.

Comment: please update the question with your HTML?